# How to get For loops to communicate with a While loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I need to write a program that takes the last number from the for loop ( if it exceeds a certain number) and places it in the while loop. I have left the unfinished code below.

```
t=0
num=int(input("How many presents do you want to buy?: "))

for i in range(num):
   t=t+int(input("Please enter the price of a present")



while t>'200':
        print("Limit Exceeded.")
        print("You need to get rid of the " #price from the previous loop
```

Comment: You have a lot of unmatched parentheses, and you cannot compare an int to a string: `t>200` will be better than `t>'200'`. I cannot really help you further, as I am not sure to understand what your are trying to achieve with this code.

Answer (score 0):

U need to use a list.

Ex

```
t = 0
num=int(input("How many presents do you want to buy?: "))
prices = []
for i in range(num):
    prices.append(int(input("Please enter the price of a present")))
    t += prices[-1]
    while t > 200:
        print("Limit Exceeded.")
        print("You need to get rid of the: {}".format(prices[-1]))
        t -= prices.pop()
```

AND
you are comparing wrongly:

```
if t > '200'
```

t is an 'int' type and you are comparing it with a string.
please correct it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The way you do it, the `while` loop will never loop more than once. You can either replace it by a `if` and keep doing the removal immediately, or place it outside of the `for` and do the removal once all prices have been added.

Comment: Well,if some guy just types 201 when he is asked the price, this program will definitely get into a endless loop. I don't exactly know what he wanna do...

Comment: I guess he is learning to code in python, let him start. He'll improve.

Comment: Add the price to `t` **after** checking that you won't go over 200.